# Objective c boolean values

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I was wondering what the difference was between the following values in objective c:

```
TRUE(uppercase) - true(lowercase) - yes
FALSE(uppercase) - false(lowercase) - no
```

they are colored differently in the IDE, are there different situations when you would use the different boolean values?

Thanks

Comment: Don't `YES` and `NO` have to always be uppercase in Objective-C?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These values are colored differently, as they are used in two different types - `BOOL` and `bool` and are different language constructs.

`BOOL` is a macro re-definition of `signed char`, which means it can have more than two values, and while the mapping is `NO`/`FALSE` == 0, `YES`/`TRUE` == 1, you have to be careful when writing boolean expressions and treat any non-zero value as true. Values that can be assigned to `BOOL` are defined as macros and are colored accordingly.

Meanwhile, `bool` on the other hand is a true boolean type and can have only two values - `true` and `false`. Its values are native language constructs and are colored as such.

Here are some other SO discussions of this topic:
[Is there a difference between YES/NO,TRUE/FALSE and true/false in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615702/is-there-a-difference-between-yes-no-true-false-and-true-false-in-objective-c)
[Objective-C : BOOL vs bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool)