# Upper boolean and lower boolean

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between YES/No,TRUE/FALSE and true/false in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615702/is-there-a-difference-between-yes-no-true-false-and-true-false-in-objective-c)

What is the difference between upper boolean and lower boolean? Ex: true and TRUE. Thanks for any answers!

Comment: No, that link is more about how a language REPRESENTS T/F, he wants to know WHY some languages use different punctuation and capitalization for T/F

Comment: @seth, both of these questions are *specifically* about Objective-C.  So how are they not duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language... Some languages only like True or False (Python), some like all lowercase (Java - I think), and some don't care (PHP, Ruby)

Comment: I'm guessing he means in Objective-C, judging from the tag.