# Why is this program produces different result with `YES` and `true`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, preprocessor-directive

Here is the full program. Can you figure out its console output?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define kEnv YES

#if kEnv
#define x @"abc"
#else
#define x @"xyz"
#endif


#define kVersion true

#if kVersion
#define y @"abc"
#else
#define y @"xyz"
#endif

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"x: %@; y: %@", x, y);
        NSLog(@"%@", kEnv ? @"abc" : @"cba");
        NSLog(@"%@", kVersion ? @"abc" : @"cba");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Before moving forward, you can copy & paste, run, and checkout the result yourself.

---

The output is:

```
x: xyz; y: abc
abc
abc
```

Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: After reading this piece of clang doc (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#discussion), I am more confused. Maybe this has something to do with the way preprocessor directive `#if` works. I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`YES` gets defined as `__objc_yes` in <objc/objc.h>, and that is a compiler-level symbol, unknown to the preprocessor.

(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/objc/objc.h on my machine.)

You can see the definition by doing

```
#define T(X) #X
#define S(X) T(X)
printf("YES is: \"%s\"\n", S(YES));
```

The C preprocessor is an interesting beast. :)

EDIT: Why does

```
#if __objc_yes
```

behave as if `__objc_yes` was false? Because `__objc_yes` is completely unknown to the preprocessor; it is known only to the compiler. This is from the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp/If.html#If) to the GNU preprocessor, but I believe it reflects the standard, about what the expression after `#if` can contain:

> [...] Identifiers that are not macros, which are all considered to be the number zero. [...]

Comment: Wait, so I can replace the `#define kEnv YES` with `#define kEnv __objc_yes`. And, why is `#if __objc_yes ` is evaluated as negative?

Answer (score 4):

If you add

```
#define YES 1
```

at the beginning you'd get the output you expect. The reason is that `YES` definition is probably more complex than the way given here and that messes up the preprocessor. You can test that by e.g. changing your test to

```
#if YES
```

(and removing my definition of YES) and you'd get the same result as you did earlier. This just shows that, however `YES` is defined, it does not trigger the

```
#if YES
```

test.

**PS**

I think if you want to use constants e.g.

```
#if XXX
```

or

```
#if XXX > 5
```

you need to define `XXX` as a numerical value otherwise the preprocessor can not perform the evaluation properly. I'd suggest you stick to just checking definitions e.g. just use

```
#ifdef XXX
```

and when you need to use

```
#if
```

only use numerical constants, not any expressions.

FWIW as mentioned here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor the preprocessor is quite limited - the reference discuss some of the limitations.

Comment: Ok, I could not find ```YES``` definition but I see you got it.

Comment: I am not looking for a way to make it right. I wanna know how this works. Redefining `YES` is not an answer to why.

Comment: Ok, see my PS added just now