# disable touch interaction in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uiview, touch

I have a UITableView that draws a subView when the user touches a cell.

The problem is that the subView drawing is animated and if the user is fast enough they can tap a cell multiple times which I want to disable during the animation and afterwards.

I've tried using this:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

and also a bool variable:

```
if (isAnimating == NO) {
```

but neither seem to work. In each case rapid touches screws up everything.

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this...
After clicking on cell set

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: .userInteractionEnabled = FALSE; Works!

Comment: Use NO instead for BOOLs in Objective-C, don't use False or FALSE

Comment: Ok, could you please tell me difference from NO to FALSE?

Comment: Basically speaking, there's no difference between NO and false, considered that you evaluate them correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615702/is-there-a-difference-between-yes-no-true-false-and-true-false-in-objective-c

Comment: In this case you lose the scroll too.

Comment: It is disabling scroll too

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question however it lacked the swift version so,
in Swift 3 it is:

```
tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
```

and to turn it back on is:

```
tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Just thought this might help someone if they were looking for the answer in swift 3 as I was, and ends up here.