# How can casting pointer to BOOL return 112?

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I have a pointer to some object, called `myObject`, and I need to know, whether it is really pointing to something. How can this code:

```
// assume MyObjectClass *myObject;
return (BOOL)myObject;
```

return **112**? I know, that I can always write

```
return (myObject == nil);
```

and everything will be fine. But until today I have always assumed, that explicit casting of *anything* to bool will *always* return `true` or `false` (as far as I know, 0 is always considered as `false` and any other value as `true`) and that BOOL with it's `YES` and `NO` values is just "renamed" bool. So basically, my questions are:

- Why is it returning 112? :-)
- Are results of explicit casting defined somewhere in C/Objective-C standard, or is it compiler-specific?

Comment: Look at the definition for BOOL. Then compare to `int a = 123; BOOL b = (BOOL)123; int c = b;` (It has *nothing* to do with pointers). I think it was C99 that introduced a proper boolean type in C .. but not sure conversions to/from it are defined. (C is not C++).

Comment: I don't know about Objective-C, but in C, there is no bool type and anything not zero is considered true.

Comment: Try `!!myObject` instead which always has an `int` value of `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objective-C, the `BOOL` macro is just a `typedef` for `signed char` with `YES`/`NO` defined, but `bool` is an actual boolean, which can be `true` or `false`.

It returns 112, because it rounds the address of your pointer to `signed char` type.

Here is some discussion with good answers:
[Objective-C : BOOL vs bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool)
[Is there a difference between YES/NO,TRUE/FALSE and true/false in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615702/is-there-a-difference-between-yes-no-true-false-and-true-false-in-objective-c)

Comment: `bool` is defined as `_bool`, but `_bool` is typedef to `int`... what's the difference, except that `BOOL` is typedef to `signed char`?

Comment: `BOOL` is a macro, `bool` is a C-standard. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5472736/1280800

Comment: Thanks for that link, maybe you could add it to your answer, for everybody else to see it instantly... accepting, btw ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "true" in C is any non-zero number. Therefore 112 would be considered true as far as C is concerned. From the C99 standard:

> 6.3.1.2 Boolean type
>
> When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal
> to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

Your value is not converted to 1 because you are converting to BOOL not _Bool. The conversion to 0/1 will be technically handled inside the if (though in reality the implementation is more likely to be (myObject != 0) inside any if/while type statement).

Answer (score 1):

In C , `bool` is a `stdbool.h` macro for boolean type `_Bool`.

And a conversion of a non-zero integer value to `_Bool` is guaranteed to yield `1`.

That is, the result of `1 == (bool) 42` is `1`.

If you are using a `BOOL` type as an alias for another integer type (like `signed char`), you can get a different result:

The result of `1 == (BOOL) 42` is `0`.