# What values should I use for iOS boolean states?

Tags: ios, boolean

It appears that in iOS I have a number of options that seem to fit for boolean values:

```
YES
NO
TRUE
FALSE
true
false
```

Which ones should I use? In this particular case I'm hiding a label, so should I set the `hidden` property to `YES`, `TRUE`, or `true`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/615702/4479896

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: you should prefer `YES` and `NO` for setting foundation properties of type `BOOL`.

For the long answer, let's first see where are these constants defined:

- `true` and `false` are from [`stdbool.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/stdbool.h.html); they are `#define`-d as `1` and `0`
- `TRUE` and `FALSE` are from `CFBase.h`; they are `#define`-d as `1` and `0`
- `YES` and `NO` are from `NSObjCRuntime.h`. This is where `signed char` is `typedef`-ed as `BOOL`, and its two values are `#define`-d as `((BOOL)1)` and `((BOOL)0)` or `__objc_yes`/`__objc_no` if `objc_bool` is supported.

The foundation classes consistently use `BOOL`, which is a `typedef` for `signed char`, to represent its boolean properties. Since the first two pairs get converted to `int` constants, using them may result in warnings, though it would probably work correctly anyway. The `YES` and `NO` constants, however, are defined in the most compatible way for your compiler, regardless of its version. Therefore, I would recommend using `YES` and `NO` consistently throughout your code.

Answer (score 6):

Actually there is no difference between `YES`, `TRUE` and `true` those all represent a true state represented by **1**.

And `NO`, `false`, `FALSE` is represents a false state represented by **0**.

You can also use:

```
BOOL aBool = 1;
```

which is equivalent to `BOOL aBool = true;` and `BOOL aBool = TRUE;` and  `BOOL aBool = YES;`

But:

```
BOOL bBool = 7;
if (bBool)
{
    NSLog(@"bBool is YES!\n");
}
if (bBool != YES) {
    NSLog("bBool is not YES!\n");
}
```

Will output like:

```
b is YES!
b is not YES!
```

This is because direct comparison with YES will fail when the value of a `BOOL` type is a non-zero value other than 1.

Here is a nice [**article**](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/of-bool-and-yes.html) for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think all of them are okay. But personally, I'd like to use `YES`/`NO`.

I found a doc called [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html):

> Boolean Values
> These macros define convenient constants to represent Boolean values.
>
> #define YES (BOOL)1
> #define NO  (BOOL)0
>
> #### Constants
>
> YES
> Defines YES as 1.
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> Declared in NSObjCRuntime.h.
>
> NO
> Defines NO as 0.
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> Declared in NSObjCRuntime.h.
>
> Declared In
> objc.h

Answer (score 0):

I share your view on this, whilst they are currently all defined the same, porting the code is a pain when you may find TRUE != true.  *(Precisely why we should never test X == 1 for TRUE as some languages use -1 and some use 1)*

I think it might be personal preference and mainly about future ports.

I follow the TRUE and FALSE options so that porting to C/C++ is easier.

You may find that true and false is better if you're regularly converting code to Java so there's less search/replaces but I found consistency with Cocoa easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use YES and NO is the same to use TRUE and FALSE or 1 and 0 respectively.

And use NSLog to view result like this little example:

```
BOOL result;
result = YES;
NSLog(@"my boolean result is %@",result ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```