# Objective-C TRUE/FALSE vs true/false

Tags: objective-c, boolean

In Objective-C we have different keywords to evaluate boolean values.  We have `YES/NO`, `TRUE/FALSE` and `(c99) true/false`.  I understand `BOOL` vs `bool` well enough and this article explains the differences wonderfully:

http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/

So what `YES/NO` means isn't my question.  My question is, what is the difference between `TRUE/FALSE` and `true/false`?  Is the uppercase version an alias for `YES/NO` or an alias for `(c99) true/false`?  Or, is it another animal altogether (like `YES/NO`) ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `YES` and `NO` identifiers are considered the standard Objective-C literals for `BOOL`.  You usually won't find `YES`, `NO`, or `BOOL` outside of Objective-C source code.  Note that these identifiers are actually macros defined in `objc/objc.h`.

The `true` and `false` identifiers are standard C99 (as you noted), if you `#include <stdbool.h>`.  Note that, since you're using Objective-C, you are probably including `stdbool.h` indirectly, even if you don't know it.  For example, `Foundation.h` includes `CoreFoundation.h`, which includes `stdbool.h`.  Thus it's pretty hard to compile a modern iOS or Mac app without getting `true` and `false`.

The `TRUE` and `FALSE` identifiers are not standard.  They are historic baggage defined by various libraries.  The libraries may have been written before the advent of C99, or written after but intended to support pre-C99 compilers, or simply written by authors ignorant of the C99 boolean literals.  On the Mac, some examples of such libraries are Kerberos, XDR/RPC, and ncurses.  Most importantly, the Mach kernel headers define `TRUE` and `FALSE` constants, and (as with `stdbool.h`) it's pretty hard to avoid these particular definitions if you're building a modern iOS or Mac app.

In all the cases I could find, `TRUE` is defined as `1` or `(1)` and `FALSE` is defined as `0` or `(0)`.

---

All of the libraries I mentioned, and the Mach kernel, predate C99 and are thus justified in defining their own boolean constants.

Objective-C's `BOOL`, `YES`, and `NO` appear in Brad Cox's [*Object-Oriented Programming: An Evolutionary Approach*](https://books.google.com/books?id=U8AgAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=BOOL) from 1991, so these identifiers are also justified.

Comment: Of all my Googling and Stack articles with similar subject, this is by far the most concise and exacting answer one could ask for.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to ncurses, the TRUE/FALSE/bool usage predates c99 and is documented in XPG4 Curses from 1996.  ncurses' configure script checks for and uses the existing c++ and c99 values when they are available.  See for example the ncurses change-log starting in [early 1997](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#index-t970321)