# How to set a conditional breakpoint in Xcode based on an object string property?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I'm looking to be able to have the debugger break when it reaches a particular string match. As an example, I might have something like this:

```
Foo myObj = [self gimmeObj];
```

`myObj` might have a property called `name`. I want the debugger to stop on the assignment when

```
[myObj.name isEqualToString:@"Bar"];
```

How can I set my conditional breakpoint in Xcode to do that?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You can set a conditional break point in Xcode by setting the breakpoint normally, then control-click on it and select Edit Breakpoint (choose Run -> Show -> Breakpoints).

In the breakpoint entry, there is a Condition column.

Now, there are several issues to keep in mind for the condition.  Firstly, gdb does not understand dot syntax, so instead of myObj.name, you must use [myObj name] (unless name is an ivar).

Next, as with most expressions in gdb, you must tell it the type of return result, namely "BOOL".  So set a condition like:

```
(BOOL)[[myObj name] isEqualToString:@"Bar"]
```

Often it is actually easier to just do this in code by temporarily adding code like:

```
if ( [myObj.name isEqualToString:@"Bar"] ) {
    NSLog( @"here" );
}
```

and then setting the break point on the NSLog.  Then your condition can be arbitrarily complex without having to worry about what gdb can and can't parse.

Comment: Except that by altering your code you run the risk of forgetting to remove your logging or altering behaviour

Comment: That's true.  I often mitigate this by adding "NYI" (Not Yet Implemented) to the string, and then my pre-release check search for NYI will catch it.

Comment: To get this working I had to make (bool) uppercase as (BOOL), probably an LLDB thing.

Comment: bool didn't work for me in GDB, I had to use BOOL or int– the difference is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/544250/725871.

Comment: I've found that putting it in code is a lot better. I had a for loop with a breakpoint stopping at a certain case of the for loop, it took 2 minutes before it finally stopped at the breakpoint. Setting it in code is a lot faster.

Comment: Symbolic links in the debugger seems more appropriate.

Comment: You can't put it in code if you have a once-every 200 game bug which has finally come up, and now you need to do a conditional breakpoint. Stopping the program to alter the code is not an option.

Comment: I found that I did not even have to add the NSLog placeholder in C++

Comment: sleep(0) is a great ad-hoc break point (NSLog(@"") is more complex)

Comment: I had to recompile and re-run the app to get the condition to work.

Comment: @justin-vallely yes, for in-application debugging lines like I mention, you have to rebuild and rerun your application, but it does mean you can use any code to set the condition.

Answer (score 31):

Here is how you do using XCode lldb conditional breakpoints.

First, double click the breakpoint (or right-click `edit breakpoint`), you can see a dialogue popup.

Updated 2021-04-22 for Xcode 12:
[image]

Here is what these options means:

1. **Condition**: The breakpoint will only fire under this condition.
2. **Ignore**: The amount of times the condition needs to meet before fire the breakpoint
3. **Action**: Action that runs after the breakpoint breaks.
4. **Options**: Automatically continue after evaluating actions

Here is a summary. For the above example in the image, it means that when the variable `testedString` is equal to `"Testing"`, break here. If I add ignore time to 1, then it will ignore the first time when `testedString` is equal to `"Testing"` and break at the second time the condition is met.

For actions, when you press add actions, there will be a list of choices. Usually what I do is to use the `Debugger Command` `po` to print variables that I need to check and I believe that there are better ways using the actions than I do.

**It seems that you have to recompile and run the app if you change the conditions at runtime**

Comment: Probably because the question was about stopping at breakpoint based on a string value [I wasn't the down-voter]

Comment: Thanks, quite helpful. This answer deserves more votes.

Comment: Updated the above example to break based on a string value now with Xcode 12 screenshot.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you can try setting a breakpoint at that line of code, open up the debugger console (Cmd+Shift+R), and type

```
condition N (int)[[myObj name] isEqualToString:@"Bar"]
```

Where N is replaced by the number of the breakpoint (an integer).

Answer (score 2):

If you mutate myObj.name using the setter, you can add a symbolic breakpoint on `-[MyObjClass setName:]` either from the Debugger Console or from the Run->Manage Breakpoints->Add Symbolic Breakpoint menu in Xcode. If not (why not? you probably shouldn't be modifying the instance variable directly except in the designated initializer or dealloc) you can set a watchpoint in gdb (use the Debugger Console in Xcode once the debugger is running). [This](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_30.html) page explains how. I don't believe Xcode exposes a UI for setting watchpoints without using the Debugger Console.

Answer (score 0):

At times when working with Frameworks (debug builds) and need to put a breakpoint in certain file/location that is hard to navigate or isn't exposed publically in framework under development. One option is to write a helper class to trigger conditional breakpoints & make step-in/step-out easier.

```
- (void)invokeFrameworkMethod {
    ...
    [DebugConditionalBreakPointHelper breakPointCondition:YES comment:@"from invokeFrameworkMethod."];
    ...
}
```

Header declaration in framework under development.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DebugConditionalBreakPointHelper : NSObject
+ (void)breakPointCondition:(BOOL)enabled comment:(NSString *)comment;
@end
```

And implementation file:

```
#import "DebugConditionalBreakPointHelper.h"

@implementation DebugConditionalBreakPointHelper
+ (void)breakPointCondition:(BOOL)enabled comment:(NSString *)comment {
    if (enabled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Triggerred Conditional Break Point. Comment: %@");
    }
}
@end
```