# Better debugger UI for gdb/iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, gdb

I'm debugging an iPhone application and, well, gdb is just not doing it for me.

Are there any alternative debuggers or debugger uis I can use for XCode in general, or specifically for debugging iPhone applications?

Comment: I'm not aware of a debugger other than gdb for XCode.  :(  You might like this as far as debugging using gdb / XCode: [Objective-C Debugging tips in Xcode4?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7650979/590956)

Comment: Are you talking about GDB from the command line (console tab) or Xcode's visual display?

Comment: I'm using Xcode, so ideally from there, but if there's a way to debug my iOS apps nicely from somewhere else, I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[lldb](http://lldb.llvm.org/) is the only supported alternative. Last time I checked it was in alpha state.

Answer (score 2):

Life was better for Apple developers when we had a choice of IDE's (CodeWarrior, Think_**_**, MPW, etc.) and debuggers (anybody remember Jasiks?), but anyways... consider this a business opportunity (to write a better debugger).

Not sure if you care to know this fact, since I have a feeling you're just not too thrilled with Xcode's built in debugging capabilities, but you **CAN** change the debugger between GDB and LLDB very easily.  Look at the "To change the debugger..." section of [Apple's Debugging & Analyzing Your Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW1) document (right at the top, within the first screen of text).