# XCode: What's the fastest way to restart my app so I can debug faster?

Tags: xcode, debugging, ios-simulator, restart

Say I am debugging and accidentally go past the function I wanted to step into. Currently, I   rerun the app again through xcode (apple+R) and have to wait for the app to load again. Is there a faster way? I looked into the stop command (apple+.) but when I load the app again from the simulator my breakpoints don't trigger.

Comment: When you say you have to "wait for the app to load again", how much time are we talking here?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting is probably your best bet, but it sounds like you may simply have too many breakpoints set if you're mindlessly hitting "Next" by the time you get to the one you want. Try turning off some of the preceding breakpoints (particularly those in loops).

If the breakpoint is in a loop, and you really only care about it under certain conditions (why else would you skip past it?), try setting it up as a conditional breakpoint that will only stop when you need it to. Check the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988621/how-to-set-a-conditional-breakpoint-in-xcode-based-on-an-object-string-property) for more info on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what i understand from the question is this : you have some breakpoints into a function...you run the app from xcode ..it didn't go into that function...then you went to simulator and run it from there and the breakpoints didn't trigger.

If that what you ment by the question ..your problem is that when you run the app from the icon in the simulator that doesn't run in debug mode it runs in release mode-ish (with some minor differences) .The debug mode only works when it's directly started from xcode (so of course your breakpoints didn't trigger).

As for the loading speed..you can't do anything about that it loads as fast as it possibly can. I personally only build and run on the actual device ..and from my experience it takes 2~4 s from the time i hit run till the app loads completely. That being said i noticed that if you have a splash screen (Default.png) it takes 1~2 s more to load so what i do is just remove the Default.png from the project , delete the app from device, restart the device, restart xcode and the screen wont be loaded every time . It may not seem like much ..per build but on the course of a few weeks of development it ads up to minutes. Also..don't forget to add the Default.png when you release it ...i forgot once and app got rejected :)

Comment: sorry for not being clear. the breakpoints trigger the first time i run. then i am stepping through the flow and i accidentally need to "go back" because I passed some function I realize I should have examined. I do this by quitting the simulator and running it again, which is taking me about 10s each time. This is taking a big toll over the long run

Comment: ah...so it's only about the speed itself...in that case the only thing you can do to speed it up is to remove the splash screen and/or set xcode and simulator to a higher priority in tasks (so it can read from disk marginally faster). Other than that...get yourself a super computer