# BOOL vs Boolean

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between `BOOL` and `Boolean` in Objective C ?

Does it matter which one is used?

If not, why do they both exist?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C : BOOL vs bool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no functional difference<sup>1</sup> between Objective-C's `BOOL` data type and the various flavors of boolean types provided by, e.g., `stdbool.h` for C. However, idiomatic Objective-C code uses the `BOOL` type (and the values `YES` and `NO`) for boolean values.

<sup>1. There are *some* differences. For example, a `BOOL` is actually a `signed char`, whereas (on my machine) `stdbool.h` defines `_Bool_` and `bool` to be an `int`.</sup>