# Having trouble with BOOL return type in Objective-C blocks

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I stumbled over a curious problem with `BOOL` return type in blocks. Having the following definition:

```
typedef BOOL (^BoolBlock)(void);
```

…this code passes:

```
BoolBlock foo = ^{ return YES; };
```

…but this fails to compile:

```
BoolBlock bar = ^{ return YES || NO; };
```

With the following error message:

> Incompatible block pointer types
>   initializing 'BoolBlock' (aka 'BOOL
>   (^)(void)') with an expression of type
>   'int (^)(void)'

I can solve the issue using an explicit cast, but shouldn’t this work without it? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably thinking the `||` operator works in languages like Ruby and Python, where it returns in the first operand that is truthy. In C, it returns 1 if either operand is truthy and 0 otherwise — that's why it thinks you're returning an integer.

Comment: Then why does something like `-(BOOL) foo { return YES || NO; }` compile? In other words, why does the distinction between integer and [BOOL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289) matter in the block case and not in the function one?

Comment: @zoul: The function has an explicit return type, so the int will be implicitly converted to a BOOL. But the block you create does not have an explicit return type, so it infers its return type from the return statement (this is a special ability that blocks have). You're returning an int, so it infers that block returns an int. Only then, after the block's type is fully inferred, does the compiler check that type against the type of the variable you're assigning it to, so you get a type mismatch.

Answer (score 15):

|| operator returns int type as Chuck said.

```
BoolBlock bar = ^{ return (BOOL)(YES || NO); };
```

or

```
BoolBlock bar = ^BOOL (void){ return YES || NO; };
BoolBlock bar = ^BOOL (){ return YES || NO; }; // warns in gcc, ok with clang
```

Comment: Thank you, stating the return type in the block definition helps and it’s a better solution than casting before return. Clang is happy with `^BOOL () {…}`.

Comment: Thanks!  I had the same problem where I was trying to use ... = BOOL^ instead of ... = ^BOOL

Answer (score 5):

As others have stated, the reason you’re getting the error is that `e0 || e1` returns an `int` regardless of the types of `e0` and `e1`. Since the compiler infers the block return type based upon the `return` statement(s), you have a block that returns `int` and you’re trying to assign it to a block variable whose block return type is `BOOL`.

I personally prefer this syntax:

```
BoolBlock bar = ^BOOL { return YES || NO };
```

to avoid the error, making it clear that the block return type is `BOOL`. The rvalue, a block literal, is understood as a block whose return type is `BOOL` and the compiler applies the usual C conversions.

As to why this happens, it’s a design decision, although it doesn’t seem to be explicitly documented.<sup>1</sup> Blocks are a new language feature. The compiler designers<sup>2</sup> have decided that they should have tighter semantics on blocks — namely, the assignment of block pointer types must have strictly matching types — and they enforce these tighter semantics when assigning a block to a block variable regardless of the rvalue being a block pointer or a block literal.

Since there’s no ISO/IEC standard covering blocks in C or C++ yet, compiler designers are free to make these decisions. Apple have submitted blocks to [ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) as [WG14/N1370](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1370.pdf) and [WG14/N1451](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1451.pdf) and, if they accept it, this behaviour (or some variant of it) should be standardised and documented.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Clang’s source code does have a comment stating that assignment of block pointers is more strict than assignment of function pointers.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>I’ve personally asked them about this.</sup>

Comment: ^BOOL {} is valid? It seems that [Blocks overview](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1370.pdf) and [Blocks proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1451.pdf) don't mention such a notation. only ^void (void){}, ^(void) {} and ^{}.

Comment: @Kazuki The proposal says ‘Closures that have a nullary argument list may specify it as such by either declaring it as (void) or by omitting the (void) entirely.’

Comment: @Kazuki Thanks for the proposal link!

Comment: @Kazuki I see what you mean. I’d say the current wording is ambiguous, and, at this moment, the compiler is the ultimate ‘standard’ (although this could be seen as a bug).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that! I didn't notice it.