# Boolean comparison of an enum

Tags: iphone, objective-c, enums, boolean, typedef

Just wondering - given that I have a typedef enum 'color' (and property of the same name) with a valid element 'blue', why is this ok:

```
 BOOL isBlue;

 if (color == blue){
     isBlue = YES;
 }
```

but this is not:

```
BOOL isBlue;

isBlue = (color == blue);
```

I've just started using enums so maybe i'm missing something simple?

Edit - as mentioned 'blue' is one of the valid elements of the enum, not a BOOL itself, i.e:

```
typedef enum { Blue, Red, Yellow } color;
```

and

```
@property color color;
```

Edit 2 - here's my actual code, as requested.  I'm a bit confused by the contradictory comments/answers.  Should I expect this to compile (it doesn't)?

.h

```
typedef enum { AddRecipes, ManageRecipes, RemoveRecipes } mode;

<snip>

@property mode mode;
```

.m

```
 @synthesize mode;

 <snip>

 BOOL modeIsAddRecipe = (mode == AddRecipes);
```

Edit 3 - for posterity I should mention that my error was trivial and unrelated.  The discussion below proved enlightening though, many thanks.

Comment: Both are perfectly valid and will compile without errors or warnings. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: @Anurag If `BOOL` is an enum that permits the values `YES` and `NO`, then the second form won't compile.

Comment: @AdamLiss - `BOOL` is a `typedef` for a `signed char`, and the values `YES` and `NO` are preprocessor definitions. See this related [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool). I'm guessing that `color` is a variable of the enum type `Color`.

Comment: @Anurag Thanks for the link.  I just skimmed through the answers to that related question, and now my head hurts.  What a mess!  :-)  Programming languages are supposed to become clearer and less error-prone as they evolve, not more complex and confusing.

Comment: Please post the code where `blue` and `color` are defined.

Comment: If (color == blue) then it will return true rather than YES. isBlue = (color == blue) ? YES : NO;

Comment: I updated the question.  @Anurag is correct, color is a variable of enum type Color.

Comment: I also added my actual code.  The error is a simple 'Expression expected'.  I might be making some other rookie error on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tia already told you, `BOOL` is defined as `signed char`, and `YES` and `NO` are defined as `(BOOL)1` and `(BOOL)0`, respectively.

It's for that reason that *both* code samples you show in your question will work just fine. In the latter snippet, the equality expression evaluates to either 1 or 0. You can freely assign these integer values to a `BOOL` (`signed char`) value.

The code will compile and run successfully, with neither an error nor a misbehavior.

If you're seeing something different, please edit your question to include your *actual* code and the error it produces, because the code you provided works just fine.

Edit (now that you've provided the actual code): I think it *should* work, but it currently doesn't (as of Xcode 4.3.1) because Clang is interpreting “`mode`” as the type `mode`, not the instance variable `mode`. If you rename the type to `RecipeMode` or change the expression to either explicitly reference the instance variable (`self->mode`) or use the property (`self.mode`), it compiles fine.

So, congratulations. You've actually (in my opinion) found a compiler bug! I suggest [reporting it](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: I added my non-compiliing code. The error is 'Expected expression'.

Comment: Error found - something too small to mention.  Thanks for provoking me to rummage in the knowledge it should work.

Comment: Bug ID is 11296187. I actually realized that I hadn't declared an iVar, only the property, so just inserted self and moved on.  But you're right, even with the iVar in place it doesn't compile.

Comment: @BenPackard: `@synthesize` creates an ivar, so an instance variable named `mode` did exist. But the compiler nonetheless preferred the type name, and then rejected your code on the grounds that a type name can't go there. `self->mode` uses the instance variable explicitly and unambiguously, and because the property provides that ivar, it will work whether you declare an ivar yourself or not.

Answer (score 3):

The `BOOL` is a simple typedef which is `signed char` (not to be confused with `bool` type)

```
typedef signed char     BOOL; 
#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

It means BOOL value can be `YES`, `NO` or anything else. For example, if you try

```
BOOL testBool = 9;
NSLog(@"%d", testBool);
```

It will print `9`. No compiler magic or runtime magic involved. This would have no problem at all until some programmer write some stupid boolean comparison like `if (testBool == YES)` instead of `if (testBool)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `BOOL` is also an enum.  The purpose of an enum is to enumerate the values that can be stored in a variable of that type.

So if your `BOOL` enum has the values `YES` and `NO`, then those are the *only* values that can be assigned to a `BOOL`.  You can't assign any other values, even if they evaluate to the same numeric values as `YES` and `NO`.

The `==` operator returns `1` or `0` (or `true` or `false`, depending on the language).  But the compiler won't allow you to assign *any* of those values to a `BOOL`, because *none* of them is `YES` or `NO`.

What you *can* do is use the ternary operator:

```
isBlue = (color == blue) ? YES : NO;
```

This evaluates the condition and returns `YES` if it's true or `NO` if it's false.

Comment: Some trivia: note that you can, in fact, assign values different than 1 (true) and 0 (false) to a boolean variable, using pointer tricks. How these hacks are handled is language-specific (some languages may consider any value greater than 0 to be true, while others will only look at the least significant bit). But this is only of academic interest, if even.

Comment: @Thomas: Good point - thanks for the clarification.  The +1 is for appropriate use of "hacks" and "academic interest."  Anyone who uses pointers to intentionally defeat type-checking or other compiler warnings on my team will be transferred immediately.  :-)

Comment: `BOOL` isn't an `enum`; it's a `typedef` for `signed char`. `YES` and `NO` are defined by macros to `(BOOL)1` and `(BOOL)0`, respectively. All three are in `<objc/objc.h>`.

Comment: @Thomas: No such tricks are necessary for `BOOL`, since it's just a `signed char`. You can assign any valid `signed char` value directly to the variable. Only C99's `_Bool` (a.k.a. `bool` if stdbool.h gets its way) can only be assigned 0 or 1 without cheating.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, I was thrown because I can usually use something like BOOL isTrue = (1 == 1).  Though maybe I shouldn't.