# Are primitive instance variables initialized by default in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, instance-variables, primitive

In the following code, is it safe to use `_test` and expect it to have a vaue of `NO`? Or do I need to always explicitly initialize it in `- (id)init`?

```
@implementation Test {
    BOOL _test;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is safe to assume that all instance variables will be initialized to 0.

This however is not the case for locally/method scoped variables which, if not manually initialized, will point to junk.

For future reference, as [Rob Napier points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10653168/732284#comment-13814806), this can be found in [the documentation for `+ (id)alloc`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc):

> The `isa` instance variable of the new instance is initialized to a data structure that describes the class; memory for all other instance variables is set to `0`.

Comment: Just to provide the reference, read the docs for `+alloc`. Specifically, all ivars except `isa` are initialized to 0, but you shouldn't be messing with `isa` anyway.

Comment: Note that auto object pointers _are_ in fact initialized to `nil` when compiled under ARC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to initialize it explicitly, mainly because of traceability and readability.
But when you look at the Definition of `BOOL`, you'll see that `NO` is nothing else than a `#define` for 0. Because of that, I assume you can safely expect `_test` to be `NO`.

a really good posting about Boolean and their handling is [Objective-C : BOOL vs bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool)