# Why is BOOL type in Objective-C a char?

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

I have been told that BOOL in Objective-C is a typedef of an unsigned char and YES & NO keywords are encoded chars. This is not the first time I heard it. I have read that this is because Apple used BOOL before the C standard provided a _Bool type, am I wrong? Is there any advantage of that fact? Are we wasting bits of memory? Does this provide a way to return valuable data in a function? Would it be correct to use it as a way to return a different values when some unexpected behavior occurs?

```
BOOL myFunction(int argument)
{
    BOOL result = YES; //The function generates the result
    if (someError == YES) {
        return 5;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool

Comment: Do you think this question is useless?

Comment: @Gopal That seems to be a link back to this question...

Comment: In C, `char` is the smallest thing you can allocate in storage.

Answer (score 5):

> Are we wasting bits of memory?

No, because you can't get a variable smaller than a `char`: it's always a single byte. You can pack multiple bits representing boolean flags in a single word, but you have to do it manually - with bit shifts, using bit fields, and so on.

> Does this provide a way to return valuable data in a function?

Not really: what you did is a hack, although `5` would definitely make its way through the system to the caller, and would be interpreted as `YES` in a "plain" `if` statement, e.g.

```
if (myFunction(123)) {
    ...
}
```

However, it would fail miserably if used like this:

```
if (myFunction(123) == YES) { // 5 != YES
    ...
}
```

> Would it be correct to use it as a way to return a different values when some unexpected behavior occurs?

It would always be incorrect from the readability point of view; as far as "doing what you meant it to do", your mileage may vary, depending on the way in which your function is used.

Comment: Might as well just return an int and be done with it. Thankyou for highlighting the readability aspect. It's a pain to maintain code from someone who has been 'clever'

Comment: Te way arround the problem: `if (myFunction(123) == YES)` is `if (!!myFunction(123) == YES)`. You will occasionally see the double negation used to convert a non-zero number to a `BOOL` `YES` value.

Comment: @Zaph Yes - that's the way really defensive programmers shield themselves against hacks of people who get fancy :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight advantage: On many platforms (including iOS, IIRC), `sizeof(_Bool) == sizeof(int)`, so using `char` can be slightly more compact.

Except `BOOL` is actually `signed char`, not `char`, this is so `@encode(BOOL)` evaluates to the same thing on all platforms. This complicates bitfields slightly, since `BOOL foo:1;` appears to define a 1-bit signed integer (IIRC the behaviour of which is undefined) — clearly `unsigned char` would be a better choice, but it was probably too late.

`_Bool` also ought to optimize better since the compiler can make assumptions about the bit-pattern used, e.g. replacing `a&&b` with `a&b` (provided `b` is side effect-free). Some architectures also represent "true" as all bits set, which is useful for masking (SSE comparison instructions come to mind).

Answer (score 0):

"BOOL in Objective-C" is not an unsigned char, it's whatever the Objective-C library defines it to be. Which is unsigned char or bool, depending on your compiler settings (32 bit or 64 bit). Both behave different. Try this code with a 32 bit compiler and a 64 bit compiler:

```
BOOL b = 256;
if (b) NSLog (@"b is true"); else NSLog (@"b is false");
```