# What's the difference between bool and BOOL?

Tags: objective-c

I think there are two boolean type we can use bool and BOOL. What's the difference between those two?

bool contains true and false; BOOL contains TRUE and FALSE, can they be interchangeable?

Answer (score 6):

[image]Mattt has written a [blog post](http://nshipster.com/bool/) about this:

> Objective-C defines BOOL to encode truth value. It is a typedef of a
>   signed char, with the macros YES and NO to represent true and false,
>   respectively.

Answer (score 2):

`bool` is the datatype defined in C99.

`BOOL` is defined in Objective-C as typedef signed char BOOL.

Check out this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool)