# How to manage a BOOL variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, boolean

I'm using a variable "volume"

```
@property BOOL * volume;
```

to set Volume On (YES) or Off (NO)

```
- (IBAction)manageVolume:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (_volume == TRUE) {
        _volume = !_volume; 
//      code...
    } else {
        _volume = !_volume;
//      code...
        }
    }
```

It Works but it return three alerts:

- `if (_volume == TRUE) {` returns `Comparison between pointer and integer ('BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') and 'int')`
- `_volume = !_volume;` returns `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') from 'int'`

How  can I solve? Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your property definition is wrong. It should not be a pointer to a `BOOL`, it should just be a `BOOL`:

```
@property BOOL volume;
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that appropriate BOOL values include `YES` and `NO`, not `true` and `false`. You should see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool) about why that is significant.