# Can't handle @"1"

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have JSON response from server, and there is bool variable coming in format 1=true, 0=false.

In my code I do this:

My first try:

```
NSString *bolean=[dict objectForKey:@"featured"];
    if ([bolean isEqualToString:@"1"]) // here application fails...
    {
        BOOL *a=[bolean boolValue];
        [newPasaka setFeatured:a];
    }
    else
    {
        BOOL *a=[bolean boolValue];
        [newPasaka setFeatured:a];
    }
```

My second try:

Here it thinks that 1 = NO, 0 = NULL

```
NSString *bolean=[dict objectForKey:@"featured"];
    if ([bolean boolValue]) //if true (1)
    {
        BOOL *a=[bolean boolValue];
        [newPasaka setFeatured:a];
    }
    else //if false (0)
    {
        BOOL *a=[bolean boolValue];
        [newPasaka setFeatured:a];
    }
```

How to workaround this?

And my class also handles this crazy.. When i setFeatured to `YES` - it sets `NO`. When i set `NO` - it sets `null.`

Here is my class:

*`.h`

```
@property BOOL *featured;
```

*`.m`

```
@synthesize featured;
```

Comment: I guess that's only example code, but I love reading stuff like `if (test) { doSomething; } else { doSomething; }`

Comment: This is very weird to use pointer to BOOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this property FROM -

```
@property BOOL *featured;
```

**TO**

```
@property (assign) BOOL featured;
```

BOOL is a primitive data type and can not be created directly as an object. However, if you need to use it as an object, wrap it inside foundation classes like `NSNumber` or `NSString`. Like this -

```
NSNumber *featuredObject = [NSNumber numberWithBool:featured];
```

And get back the value like this -

```
BOOL featured = [featuredObject boolValue];
```

Confused about bool vs BOOL? Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool).

Comment: Although this is correct, please explain _why_ this is the solution (and also, the `BOOL *a` in the code also needs to be changed).

Comment: @Dharmbir Choudhary: Your edit was incorrect. Please revert it.

Comment: @Dharmbir Choudhary: No. Now you've made it worse.

Comment: can you also help me how to predicate find bools?

Comment: NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.featured=YES"];?

Comment: here one mistake is there in Bool variable you cannot put * symbol

Comment: @Cheese: Please don't ask new questions in _comments_, create a new question instead.

Answer (score 3):

BOOL is not a class, is primitive type

```
BOOL a = [bolean boolValue];
```

not

```
BOOL *a = [bolean boolValue]; // this is wront
```

Anyway with JSON that value should be rapresented as a Number, not a String, unless the API you are dealing with, force that value to be a string. Put a breakpoint in after the objectForKey and print in console the class of the 'bolean' object:

```
po [bolean class]
```

so you will sure about the kind of object you are dealing with, and then in case of a Number (as should be) just use [bolean boolValue]

Answer (score 0):

BOOL is primitive type, so you need not to use pointer with it.

Change this property from

```
@property BOOL *featured;
```

to

```
@property BOOL featured;
```

Then you need to replace this code:

```
NSString *bolean=[dict objectForKey:@"featured"];
    if ([bolean isEqualToString:@"1"]) // here application fails...
    {
        BOOL *a=[bolean boolValue];
        [newPasaka setFeatured:a];
    }
    else
    {
        BOOL *a=[bolean boolValue];
        [newPasaka setFeatured:a];
    }
```

with this:

```
NSString *bolean=[dict objectForKey:@"featured"];
[newPasaka setFeatured:[boolean boolValue]]
```

It is greatly simplified and works fine

Answer (score 0):

One more way you can do is have modified below:-

```
@property (assign) Bool featured;
NSString *bolean=[dict objectForKey:@"featured"];
Bool yourBoolValue=[bolean boolValue];
    if (yourBoolValue==1]) // here if (true)
    {
        Bool a=yourBoolValue;
        [newPasaka setFeatured:a];
    }
    else//if (false)
    {
        Bool a=yourBoolValue;
        [newPasaka setFeatured:a];
    }
```

Comment: `Bool` is not a valid type in Objective-C. Either `bool` or `BOOL`. Also, you don't check for `1` but for `YES` or `true` instead (or not at all, since `if (yourBoolValue)` is sufficient).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `dict` is the deserialized JSON object, and the boolean value was represented as a JSON number (either 0 or 1), then you obtain a boolean value as follows:

```
BOOL isFeatured = [dict[@"featured"] boolValue];
```

Or your code can be written as:

```
[newPasaka setFeatured:[dict[@"featured"] boolValue]];
```

Or utilizing Ashok's corrected property declaration:

```
newPaska.featured = [dict[@"featured"] boolValue];
```

;)