# 2048 casted to BOOL returns 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, boolean

Consider this code

```
NSInteger q = 2048;
BOOL boolQ = q;

NSLog(@"%hhd",boolQ);
```

After execution boolQ is equal 0. Could someone explain why is this so?

Comment: Why `%hhd`? I got 1 in NSLog.

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya Give more explanation about your point? That's question here...

Comment: @Mani check this bolg http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/

Comment: see this post. may get more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BOOL probably is implemented as `char` or `uint8_t`/`int8_t`, as `"hh"` prints half of the half of an integer. which typically is a byte.

Converting to `char` is taking the lowest 8bit of `2048` (=`0x800`) and gives you `0`.

The proper way to convert any integer to a boolean value is:

```
NSInteger q = some-value;
BOOL b = !!q;
```

Comment: this makes sense, but if u debug it you will see that BOOL value is actually NO, I added NSLog hdd just to print it. If you stop on breakpoint above NSLog line you can inspect that boolQ is NO.

Comment: As per this answer `http://stackoverflow.com/a/544250/694576` `NO` is just a `#define` for `(BOOL) 0`. @haawa

Answer (score 0):

Casting an integer value to a type too small to represent the value being converted is undefined behaviour in C (C11 standard Annex J.2), and therefore also in the part of Objective-C which deals with C-level matters. Since it's undefined behaviour it can represent the result however it wants, expected value or not.

As per 6.3.1.4, any integer can be used *as* a boolean value without casting, in which case it will show the expected behaviour (0 is 0, everything else is 1), giving rise to the `!!` idiom suggested by alk; perhaps counterintuitively, you convert the value by *not* explicitly converting the value (instead, the conversion is correctly handled by the implicit conversion operation inserted by the `!` operator).