# Flipping a BOOL value

Tags: objective-c

I have a program in which I want to flip a BOOL value without doing this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL *boolValue;

if (boolValue == YES) {
    boolValue = NO;
}
if (boolValue == NO) {
    boolValue = YES;
}
```

Is there a method I can use to switch the value without using this way?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool); looks like you can just `boolValue ^= 1`.

Comment: Kenney has the right idea.  At the very least, for the second statement you can use an `else`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several things wrong here.

1. Don't make the property a `BOOL *`, make it just a `BOOL`.
2. Never check a `BOOL` value directly against `YES` or `NO`.
3. Toggling a `BOOL` is done by `boolValue = !boolValue;`.

Your code becomes:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL boolValue;

boolValue = !boolValue; // "flip" the BOOL value
```

BTW - for point #2 you should write such `if` statements like this:

```
if (boolValue) { // is it YES?
```

or:

```
if (!boolValue) { // is it NO?
```

But neither are needed to flip the value.