# BOOL vs bool in iOS

Tags: ios, boolean

Boy do I feel stupid. Here is a programming 101 question that I just can't figure out.

```
BOOL MOMisCompatible = [self.objectModel isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:existingPersistentStoreMetadata];

    NSLog(@"%d", (unsigned)MOMisCompatible); // A

    if(MOMisCompatible){
        NSLog(@"The MOM is compatible."); // B
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"ARGH! The MOM is incompatible."); // C
    }
```

The NSLog outputs 1 or 0 at A as expected.
But neither B nor C outputs anything.
I debug by putting a breakpoint at A, but the code never drops into A nor B.
What am I missing?

Comment: Hmmm; that doesn't make sense.  Are you sure that's the actual code?

Comment: I had it once that a break point didn't get hit even though the log was printed. Check if you have included a `.m`-File somewhere instead of the `.h`-File.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool) answer explains the above in best possible way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is something related to their typedef, "BOOL" is a signed char and its header is objc.h, "bool" on the other hand is an int with header stdbool.h. Thus when you try to cast it to (unsigned) it actually works

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If the value is printing `0` or `1` then the `if` statements should work regardless of their type.

Comment: it is typedef signed char for NOT  arm64 and it can't stop debugger