# Why i can not assign true to a BOOL in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

Created a `BOOL *myBool` variable in implementation file as below:

```
@interface myClass ()

{
    BOOL *myBool;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {        
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myBool = false; // no error
 }
- (IBAction)myBtnClickd:(UIButton *)sender {                
    if (!myBool) { 

        myBool = true; //error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to BOOL from int.            
    }        
    else { 

        myBool = false;                         
    }                
}
```

why I can not assign true to it and I am not assigning any `int` as we can see in the code, I do not want to make it a property.

Comment: remove * from BOOL *myBool;

Comment: myBool = false; // works fine because, it converts to 0 which is NULL and assignable to pointer. myBool = true, it converts to 1 and not valid value for pointer.

Comment: @un thanks but if it not a reference type what type it is ?

Comment: @ios_Dev it is a value type

Comment: @Unheilig i am not able to upvote , may be i have low reputation, i will do it as soon as i could.
thanks for the link, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign true to BOOL, because you are not trying to assign to BOOL, but to BOOL*. A pointer to BOOL. Assigning false to a BOOL* works for some weird reasons deeply hidden in the C standard.

Anyway, this is Objective-C. Why are you using true and false in Objective-C? It's either YES or NO.

Anyway, what is that nonsense code? Just write myBool = ! myBool.

Anyway, what are you doing having instance variables in an Objective-C class that don't start with an underscore, and why are you not using properties? That code should be either

```
self.myBool = ! self.myBool;
```

or

```
_myBool = ! _myBool;
```

And of course the BOOL* should be a BOOL. BOOL is not a reference type, it's a value type.

Comment: Thankyou what is the difference between assigning true false & YES NO ?

Comment: **what are you doing having instance variables in an Objective-C class that don't start with an underscore**
Sir i am kind of new to this , can you please explain why the instance variables should start with underscore (i.e. properties i guess)

Assigning false to a BOOL* works because this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool]

Comment: YES and NO are Objective C coding conventions. Instance variables starting with underscore are Objective C coding conventions. That way a reader sees immediately that you are using an instance variable, and not a local variable, parameter, global variable, extern global variable, enum, or whatever, but an instance variable. Using properties will save your life at some point.

Comment: i was told to use properties , when i need to access it from another class, should i always be using properties ?