# Calling C function taking bool, not BOOL, from ObjC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, types

Within my ObjC code, I am calling a function which has an argument of type `bool` (not `BOOL`).

Should I be passing `YES` to this argument from my ObjC code, or would passing `true` should be correct?

This question is about conventions, not functional correctness.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your build settings. See the related answer [Objective-C : BOOL vs bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool)

`BOOL` and `bool` can refer to the same type but sometimes they don't.

To be safe, always use the correct type, that is, `false` and `true` for `bool`.

The difference can be seen mostly in rare edge cases but if it appears, it's really difficult to find.

For the same reason we use `NULL` instead of `nil` when interacting with C APIs, even if they both are usually just a macro for `0`. Their types still differ.

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan, my question is more about what's the convention here, as for functionally, I bet i cannot contrive an example which demonstrate a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The *convention*, if one exists in any formal sense, would be for `bool`/`true`/`false` and `BOOL`/`YES`/`NO`.

As for *functional correctness* you are correct that it is hard (but not impossible[1]) to "contrive an example which demonstrates a difference". Boolean logic in C is based on integers, "boolean" valued operators (`>`, `&&`, *et al*) return integers not any flavour of boolean.

HTH

---

[1] E.g. consider uses of `@encode` and different platforms (macOS, iOS, etc.) if you wish to contrive something.